# $\sum ||x_n||_X <\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$ does'nt implies $\sum x_n$ convergence in $X$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I know that X is Banach iff $\sum ||x_n||_X <\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$ implies $\sum x_n$ convergence in $X$.

And I'm looking for a counterexample in a non Banach space, like $c_{00} \subset l^\infty$. My try is:

Take $(x_n)_n \subset c_{00}$ defined by

\begin{equation}
x_n=(y_k^n)_k=1/n^2 \text{ if } n=k  \text{ and } 0 \text{ otherwise.}
\end{equation}

Then $||x_n||_{\infty}=1/n^2$ and $\sum ||x_n||_\infty<\infty$.

Till this part I think it's fine. But i don't know how to procced. The fact that $(y_k^n)\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$, implies that $\sum x_n$ does'nt lies in $c_{00}$? That's it? I'm confused on deciding if $\sum x_n$ converges or not... Thanks!

Comment: More generally, if $Y$ is dense in Banach space $X$, then any point of $x$ can be obtained as the sum of a series $\sum x_n$ with $x_n \in Y$ and $\sum \|x_n\| < + \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $y \in c_{00}$ is the infinite sum. The strategy is to show that $y$ must take the form we expect, i.e. $y_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ for all $n$, then observe that this contradicts $y \in c_{00}$.

Note that, for each $n$, the map $f_n : x \mapsto x_n$ is a bounded linear map from $c_{00}$ to $\Bbb{R}$ (or $\Bbb{C}$; it doesn't matter). It's a straightforward consequence of the definitions of addition and scalar multiplication in $c_{00}$ that the map is linear. To see that it's bounded,
$$|f_n(x)| = |x_n| \le \sup_{m \in \Bbb{N}} |x_m| = \|x\|_\infty.$$
Thus, using both linearity and continuity,
$$y_n = f_n(y) = f_n\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty y^k\right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_n\left(y^k\right) = \frac{1}{n^2}.$$
Thus, $y_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ for all $n$, as expected, but such a sequence does not belong in $c_{00}$.

Comment: fair enough, my friend! Thank you for the clarification.